# Objectlistview ModelFilter won't react

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm trying to create some search mechanic on a ObjectListView control. According to the documentation this can be done by adding a TextMatchFilter to the control:

> this.olv1.ModelFilter = TextMatchFilter.Contains(this.olv1, "search");
>
> After executing this line, the olv1 will only show rows where the text “search” occurs in at least one cell of that row.

This is what I have done so far:

```
private void textBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    projectObjectListView.ModelFilter = TextMatchFilter.Contains(projectObjectListView, toolStripTextBox_search.Text);
}
```

Whenever I type in my textbox the TextMatchFilter is set to my ObjectListView. I have set all columns to be searchable but when I start typing, nothing happens. The event fires as it should and the Filter get set to the OLV Modelfilter, but no reaction. Anyone have experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `UseFiltering` property on the `ObjectListView` to true, otherwise the OLV will ignore any assigned `ModelFilter`.

> To enable filtering on a list, you must set UseFiltering to true. To ensure backward compatibility, it is false by default.

[Source](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/filtering.html#ixzz2mRdIF451)

Comment: I have set my UseFiltering to true but still it's not working. I use detail as view type is it because of that? My first column searchable property is set to true and rest is false since I only want to search in first column

Comment: @ShinoLex: Filtering on detail view works fine. Must be something else.

Comment: Yes I realized I did something wrong on initialize, its working now.

Comment: I did realized when I use filter for searching it's highlighting next character sometimes? Like I type ma and if there is Manheim it will highlight man

Comment: @ShinoLex: I do not remember that happening.

Comment: TextMatchFilter filter = TextMatchFilter.Contains(olvMediaProp, SearchStr);
            
            olvMediaProp.ModelFilter = filter;
            olvMediaProp.DefaultRenderer = new HighlightTextRenderer(filter);
            HighlightTextRenderer renderer = olvMediaProp.DefaultRenderer as HighlightTextRenderer;
            if(renderer!=null)
            {
                SolidBrush brush = renderer.FillBrush as SolidBrush ?? new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Red);
            }
This is how I set my colored hightlight